# How to filter only percent symbol (%) in LIKE statement

Tags: delphi

There are three records in clientdataset

1. 123+%1
2. 123+%
3. 123+&

I use the filter

```
DataSet.Filter := ' Column LIKE ''%123+%'' '
```

And the result show three records.
How can i filter to get item 1, 2 items instead of the third one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since "%" in SQL is usually used as a wildcard character, you will have to escape it if you want to search for the character itself.
So

```
DataSet.Filter := ' Column LIKE ''%123+\%%''
```

should do it. 
The first "\%" escaped % means, it will be looking for the character itself, and the second one after that, that anything else ( in your example the "1") can come after that.